# R: vector or matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Example code:

```
> sapply(list(1:3,25:29),median)
[1]  2 27
```

Is this output considered to be a vector or a matrix?  Is there a command that I can use to determine this kind of information directly?

Comment: `is.vector(sapply(list(1:3,25:29),median))` to test it. The general pattern in R is `as.xxx` to convert and `is.xxx` to test.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  I'm trying to learn here.  Back in the day when SO originated, short questions like this were actually **upvoted**.  Questions even shorter than this, in fact.  I feel like I'm being indirectly pressured to delete this question, even though the comment provided by thelatemail was very helpful and didactic.  If I "improve" my question by adding fat to it in an attempt to gain favor with the downvoters, it will not improve the quality of the question.  So guess what: I'm keeping this question.  Cheers!

Comment: You can display the class of an object using class() in your case class(sapply(list(1:3,25:29),median)) and, as already show, you can explicitly define the class using as.xxx() or test using is.xxx().

Comment: You can tell from the output format that it is not a matrix. You could see if it had a dimension with `dim(obj). `sapply` uses simplify2array but then it drops single dimensions.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. To explain the downvoters (of which I am not one), they probably stem from this being fairly simple stuff that could have been found with some quick Googling - e.g. http://www.statmethods.net/management/typeconversion.html is on the first page after searching for `R vector matrix`.

Comment: Down voters: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not

Comment: @thelatemail I really appreciate your help, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Hat-tip and thank you to `thelatemail`:

```
> is.vector(sapply(list(1:3,25:29),median))
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(sapply(list(1:3,25:29),median))
[1] FALSE
```

As mentioned by him: The general pattern in R is `as.xxx` to convert and `is.xxx` to test.